# Can you weight paint UV verts to a bone separately?

Tags: animation, uv, armature

So I'm making a female robot character with a similar design style to the classic megaman characters, but her eyes are going to be lenses instead of spheres. As such I was wondering if it is possible to assign skeleton bone weight to unwrapped UV vertices so it slides them over the texture without moving the physical vertices, as that would look rather odd.
Basically separating the UV vertices from the 3D vertices to form an effect not unlike that of a piece of paper with a circle cut in it moving over a picture.

Comment: yes.​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation, could you elaborate on the process or link a tutorial please?

Comment: I didn't mean to sound like a jerk. Let me explain. You said "is it possible to do X" and in most cases the answer is yes. [Here](https://gooseberry.blender.org/caterpillar-making-of-animating-uvs/) is a write up of how animating UV was done in Cosmos Laundromat.

Comment: Ah no, You're fine. I understand the logic behind your answer. I was looking for a process more than a yes or no. Thanks for the link though it's a great start.